# updating relational database in asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, relational-database

I am developing a simple blog application to teach myself C# and asp .net mvc3. 
I am stuck at a stage where I need to update comments to a post.

Comment class in my code is as follows:

```
 public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string CommentBody { get; set; }

        public int BlogID { get; set; } 
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a comment form on the blog details page which takes the name, email and comment. The code is as follow:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
    </div>  
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
    </div>            

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.CommentBody)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.CommentBody)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.CommentBody)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
    </p>
```

I am not sure how to pass the blogid with this so that the comment gets updated with the correct blogid.

thanks.

Comment: What are you doing in your action? Can you add the action code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hidden field inside the form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Comment.BlogID)
```

Comment: introducing a hiddenform gives this error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Comments_Blogs_BlogID". The conflict occurred in database "NPLHBlogDb", table "dbo.Blogs", column 'BlogID'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I guess that's because your Blog property is null. You will have to use the BlogID property to fetch from the database the actual Blog before inserting the comment.

Comment: I tried doing this @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Comment.BlogID, Model.Blog.BlogID). This doesn't work. I can see that a null value is being passed to comment controller. However, I do not know how to pass the correct value.

Comment: You will have to fetch it from your database. If you wanted to populate the entire Blog property you will have to use hidden fields for each of its properties: `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Comment.Blog.Prop1)` and so on...

Comment: Apologies for being annoying but I am not getting it, I want to set the comment.BlogID to be equal to the id of the blog post the comment is being made.

Comment: And what's the issue with it? When you call the GET action you are fetching the Blog object from your database, so all your model properties are properly populated. Then inside the form you need to use a hidden field in order to persist the BlogId so that in your POST controller action retrieve it back.

Comment: I guess I have complicated the situation. I have a BlogController which had Detail method that returns a viewModel. This viewModel is strongly typed against BlogDetailViewModel which just holds both Blog.cs and Comment.cs. A comment form is placed at the end of the post which posts to "Create" action of "comment" controller. Therefore, it pass a null value if I set the hiddenfor field to x.Comment.BlogID

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13210/discussion-between-tripping-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Comment.BlogID)
```

Comment: how will this pick up the correct BlogID for the new comment?

Comment: introducing a hiddenform gives this error:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Comments_Blogs_BlogID". The conflict occurred in database "NPLHBlogDb", table "dbo.Blogs", column 'BlogID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Maybe you have something more than the Comment property in your model; the comment belongs to a blog, so you can add that blog reference in your model. Once you have it use an Html.Hidden, specify the name of the field and use the value of Blog.BlogID for it, instead of using Html.HiddenFor.